# Deciding whether to end a line with a character or not in lstlisting

Tags: formatting, listings, verbatim, highlighting, code

I need to write a document where there are written inputs and outputs of unix command line interface software (through bash).
For example I need to show something like:

```
$ git log --pretty=format:"%h %ad | %s%d [%an]" --graph --date=short --all
* 1c0435a 2013-08-17 | Aggiunta del telefono (HEAD, master) 
* 928406c 2013-08-17 | Il mio primo commit modificato (v1, origin/master) 
* 8a3b838 2013-08-17 | Il mio primo commit (v1-beta)
```

where the first line is the bash prompt, and the 2nd-4th lines are the software's output (git in this case).

As you know, bash-prompt's too long lines need to have a back slash \ as carriage return, otherwise bash doesn't count it as one line, but as two different lines. So, if you need to break the 1st line you have to write

```
 $ git log --pretty=format:"%h %ad | %s%d [%an]" \
         --graph --date=short --all
```

Obviously, while you'll want a back slash on prompt's broken lines, you do not want it on output lines. So, even though you DO WANT to break lines 2nd-4th, you don't want the slash:

WRONG

```
   * 1c0435a 2013-08-17 | Aggiunta del \
telefono (HEAD, master) 
    * 928406c 2013-08-17 | Il mio primo commit \
 modificato (v1, origin/master) 
    * 8a3b838 2013-08-17 | Il mio primo commit \
(v1-beta)
```

CORRECT

```
    * 1c0435a 2013-08-17 | Aggiunta del 
telefono (HEAD, master) 
    * 928406c 2013-08-17 | Il mio primo commit 
 modificato (v1, origin/master) 
    * 8a3b838 2013-08-17 | Il mio primo commit 
(v1-beta)
```

The perfect solution would be letting me decide where to break the line with a 
back slash, and where to break it without the back slash.
Do you have any ideas on how to accomplish this?
I mean something like

```
moredelim=[is][pbreak=\small\symbol{'134}]{§§}{§§}
```

(I know this example doesn't work, it's just to let you know what I mean: it's intended to break with \ only lines that I escape within the §§)
Here is my lstset:

```
\lstset{ %
language=xml,                % choose the language of the code
basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,% \footnotesize,       % the size of the fonts that are used for the code
numbers=left,                   % where to put the line-numbers
numberstyle=\footnotesize,      % the size of the fonts that are used for the line-numbers
stepnumber=1,                   % the step between two line-numbers. If it is 1 each line will be numbered
numbersep=5pt,                  % how far the line-numbers are from the code
backgroundcolor=\color{white},  % choose the background color. You must add \usepackage{color}
showspaces=false,               % show spaces adding particular underscores
showstringspaces=false,         % underline spaces within strings
showtabs=false,                 % show tabs within strings adding particular underscores
frame=single,           % adds a frame around the code
tabsize=2,          % sets default tabsize to 2 spaces
captionpos=b,           % sets the caption-position to bottom
breaklines=true,        % sets automatic line breaking
prebreak=\small\symbol{'134},
breakatwhitespace=false,    % sets if automatic breaks should only happen at whitespace
moredelim=[is][\bfseries]{@@}{@@}
}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand correctly. Is the problem solved if you add `literate={\\}{{}}0` in the `\lstset` options?

Comment: Actually it is not. The problem is that I need to have the possibility to chose wether break the line with a backslash or break the line without it ...